# Merge 2 decks with different numbers

Tags: swift, algorithm

I have to merge a set of chains and I'm kind of stuck, let's put a deck as an example. Let's say I have 2 set of numbers:

```
deck1 = [1, 2]
deck2 = [1, 15, 2]
```

I want to find all equal and different # in it and store it into a new deck, the expected outcome is:

```
[1, 15, 2]
```

where I care about the previous order of the array ex: [1, 2] but not about the new one, so the new one should come out like: [1, 2, 15] or [1, 15, 2] only those two cases.

For that I created a double loop:

```
var newDeck = []

for deck1 in deck1 {
    for deck2 in deck2 {
        if(deck1 == deck2) {
            newDeck.append(deck1)
        } else {
            
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to do the == part but I'm not sure about the else. A solution I came up with was adding another loop (lol) in the else and then I realized I needed help. How can I solve that little puzzle?

Thanks

Edit: Another idea that I was thinking now is adding the values of the first loop into a diccionary and if it's not there then add it, but wouldn't the performance decrease with that as well?

Comment: You should research the [Set](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set) collection type, it can be really useful for this kind of problem.

Comment: ok looking @JoakimDanielson

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the problem of sets for what I see is that when you store it, it has no defined order. I need the items to be ordered

Comment: You don’t need to store the values in a set , you can just use them as an interim solution to find equal and different values

Comment: Your sample with its "expected outcome" is unclear. You might want to have a different input and show the expected output, because currently, it's `deck2`, but why?

Comment: I think the expected outcome is very clear, you have 1,23 and 1,2, the expected outcome is to have into a variable 1,2,3 . A merge set of numbers @Larme

Comment: You are talking about order that set doesn't have. So the order, is the index (of the initial value) or the value? Because, if it's the value, using a Set would be indeed the quickest way to do so, and then sort it.

Comment: Hm... yeah it's a set of chains, like I care about the previous order but not the new one. I'll recheck what I wrote above

Comment: What if deck1 was `1, 3, 2`?  Since you for "1,2" & "1, 15, 2", you accept only "1, 2, 15" & "1, 15, 2", and not "15, 1, 2" nor "15, 2, 1", "2, 15, 1", etc. I'm trying to find a logic on the "accepted case order".

Comment: in that case it would have to be either `1, 3, 15, 2` or `1, 15, 3, 2` doesn't matter. For decks: deck1 = [1, 3, 2] and deck2 = [1, 15, 2] @Larme

Comment: Do I miss something ? Why not loop over elements of second array. Test if item is not in array1; if so, append item to array1. At the end, array1 has all elements, once.

Comment: @claude31 because that would not be in the desired order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way is to get the difference with [CollectionDifference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collectiondifference) and apply only the insertions

```
let deck1 = [1, 2]
let deck2 = [1, 15, 2]

var result = deck2

let difference = deck1.difference(from: deck2)
for change in difference {
    if case let .insert(offset, newElement, _) = change {
        result.insert(newElement, at: offset)
    }
}

print(result)
```

Comment: Nice approach. The only downside is that `CollectionDifference` is iOS 13+ (in case of dev like me still needing iOS 12+)

Comment: @Larme lucky me I'm using iOS 15 hahaha

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the logic that you aren't totally explaining...

I think the logic is:
We check the element at index 0 of both array, we insert them into the result if it's not present already. 
We check the element at index 1 of both array, we insert them into the result if it's not present already. 
We check the element at index 2 of both array, we insert them into the result if it's not present already. 
And so on...

But as said in comment, I'm not certain, you don't explain it fully and your samples can be misinterpreted, as they don't cover all the cases (and it's not explained why some value should be there or not).

So, both methods should do the trick. I kept a `Set` version to illustrate, since they don't have duplicate and finding should then be quicker...

To avoid an out of bound, I checked the smaller array, and keep the last values into `rest`.

```
func merge(deck1: [Int], deck2: [Int]) {
    var valuesAlreadySaved: Set<Int> = Set()

    var result: [Int] = []
    var rest: [Int] = []
    let min = min(deck1.count, deck2.count)
    if deck1.count > min {
        rest.append(contentsOf: deck1.dropFirst(min))
    } else {
        rest.append(contentsOf: deck2.dropFirst(min))
    }
    print("Rest: \(rest)")
    for index in 0..<min {
        let value1 = deck1[index]
        let value2 = deck2[index]
        if !valuesAlreadySaved.contains(value1) {
            result.append(value1)
            valuesAlreadySaved.insert(value1)
        }
        if !valuesAlreadySaved.contains(value2) {
            result.append(value2)
            valuesAlreadySaved.insert(value2)
        }
    }

    for aValue in rest {
        if !valuesAlreadySaved.contains(aValue) {
            result.append(aValue)
            valuesAlreadySaved.insert(aValue)
        }
    }

    print("Input: \(deck1) - \(deck2)")
    print("Result: \(result)")
}

merge(deck1: [1, 2], deck2: [1, 15, 2])
merge(deck1: [1, 3, 2], deck2: [1, 15, 2])

func mergeWithoutSet(deck1: [Int], deck2: [Int]) {

    var result: [Int] = []
    var rest: [Int] = []
    let min = min(deck1.count, deck2.count)
    if deck1.count > min {
        rest.append(contentsOf: deck1.dropFirst(min))
    } else {
        rest.append(contentsOf: deck2.dropFirst(min))
    }
    print("Rest2: \(rest)")
    for index in 0..<min {
        let value1 = deck1[index]
        if !result.contains(value1) {
            result.append(value1)
        }
        let value2 = deck2[index]
        if !result.contains(value2) {
            result.append(value2)
        }
    }

    for aValue in rest {
        if !result.contains(aValue) {
            result.append(aValue)
        }
    }

    print("Input2: \(deck1) - \(deck2)")
    print("Result2: \(result)")
}

mergeWithoutSet(deck1: [1, 2], deck2: [1, 15, 2])
mergeWithoutSet(deck1: [1, 3, 2], deck2: [1, 15, 2])
```

And it could be factorized with:

```
func mergeWithoutSet2(deck1: [Int], deck2: [Int]) {

    var result: [Int] = []
    let min = min(deck1.count, deck2.count)
    let rest = deck1.count > min ? deck1.dropFirst(min) : deck2.dropFirst(min)
    print("Rest3: \(rest)")

    func appendIfNeeded(_ value: Int, to array: inout [Int]) {
        guard !array.contains(value) else { return }
        array.append(value)
    }
    for index in 0..<min {
        appendIfNeeded(deck1[index], to: &result)
        appendIfNeeded(deck2[index], to: &result)
    }

    for aValue in rest {
        appendIfNeeded(aValue, to: &result)
    }

    print("Input3: \(deck1) - \(deck2)")
    print("Result3: \(result)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first method is to sum two arrays, and then use the `contains` function to check the new array for values and eliminate redundancy.

```swift
let deck1 = [1, 2]
let deck2 = [1, 15, 2]

var deck = deck1 + deck2

var newDeck = [Int]()
for i in deck {
    if newDeck.contains(i) == false {
        newDeck.append(i)
    }
}
print(newDeck)
```

The second way is to use the `Set`. Combine the two arrays and convert them into sets. The set does not allow redundancy, so the duplicate value is automatically removed. After that, change it back to the arrangement.

```swift
let deck1 = [1, 2]
let deck2 = [1, 15, 2]

var deck = deck1 + deck2

let newDeck: Set = Set(deck)
Array(newDeck)
```